Deploy laraavel + vue + vite en railway
Tengo el siguiente error al hacer deploy en un proyecyto realizado con laravel 10 + vite, el deploy lo hago en railway:

Dockerfile:25

23 |     # build phase
24 |     COPY . /app/.
25 | >>> RUN  npm run build && composer install && php artisan
optimize:clear && php artisan storage:link && php artisan migrate
--force && php artisan passport:keys
26 |
27 |

ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/bash -ol pipefail -c npm run
build && composer install && php artisan optimize:clear && php artisan
storage:link && php artisan migrate --force && php artisan
passport:keys" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
Error: Docker build failed


Yo tenia el mismo error al querer hacer el deploy en railway, la solucion que encontre fue la de modificar el NIXPACKS_BUILD_CMD, solamente deje composer install && chmod 775 storage/ && chmod 775 bootstrap/cache dentro de dicha variable, y luego por terminal ejecute el php artisan migrate --force al iniciar el deploy.

Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas en el centro de ayuda.
